# Interception android with aspectj

Tags: android, http, url, aspectj, pointcut

Is it possible, using aspect intercept URL from activity ?

```
    pointcut callHttpResponse() : 
    call(* org.apache.http.HttpResponse..*.*(..));
```

Comment: In principle, yes, but it depends on your use case. Do you control the calling code, i.e. can you weave into it? Give us some more information, there is insufficient information.

Comment: i only test this code ,this is my first time to use aspectj with android.

Comment: Which makes it even easier. You should have some minimal test sample to play with. Sorry guy, if you cannot explain any better what you want to do, it will be hard to answer your question. For the time being I will vote to close the question and recommend to you to read some AspectJ documentation if you are unwilling to provide even a little bit of context in your question.

Comment: my problem is how can i intersept all request http with aspectj in android?